# Can electronic device help with glaucoma?

Tags: ophthalmology, optic-nerve, glaucoma

[Retinal implants](http://www.nature.com/news/fda-approves-first-retinal-implant-1.12439) have been used in retinitis pigmentosa to restore some vision when the optic nerve is still intact, and experimental [cortical implants](http://www.pages.drexel.edu/~dh329/bmes212/cortical.html) when the optic nerve is damaged.

Are these devices suitable for those who have either fully or partially lost vision from glaucoma?

Comment: Can you point/link what kind of electronic devices you're in mind?